# How to remove "Top sites and news feed tab" in new Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

After Creators Update Windows offered to show news feed tab in new tabs. Unfortunately, after accepting, it reliably freezes whenever I open a new tab. I failed to find the option to switch to previous behavior. Where is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course, I found it very soon after asking the question: `Tools > Internet Options > Tabs > When a new tab is opened, open`. Leaving this in place in case it helps someone else with the same problem...

Comment: For anyone else who missed it, `Tabs` is a button about half way down in the `General` tab of the options panel.